# \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap} \usepackage{fancyhdr}

Tags: naming, fncychap

Can I change "Chapter" with "Year"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated `\chaptername` to `Year`. The default is `Chapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Year}% Chapters are now called Years

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2016}

\chapter{The year after 2016}

\end{document}
```